# PHP - mySQL "like" query return nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I know that this is same with a lot of other posts here but i can't figure it out!

my code looks like this:

```
$i=0;
$shelves = array();
$shelves['position'] = array();
$query = "select id, cat_id, book_title, writer, publisher, issue_year, copies, abstract from library where $table like '%$search_param%'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
   error_log($data['id']);
   $shelves['position'][$i]['id'] = $data['id'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['cat_id'] = $data['cat_id'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['book_title'] = $data['book_title'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['writer'] = $data['writer'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['publisher'] = $data['publisher'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['issue_year'] = $data['issue_year'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['copies'] = $data['copies'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['abstract'] = $data['abstract'];
   ++$i;
}
error_log( count($shelves['position']) );
```

And because there are tones of other posts like this one i tried their solution:

```
$query = sprintf("select id, cat_id, book_title, writer, publisher, issue_year, copies, abstract from library where %s like'%%%s%'",mysql_real_escape_string($table),mysql_real_escape_string($search_param) );
```

Or Something like that:

```
$query = "select id, cat_id, book_title, writer, publisher, issue_year, copies, abstract from library where $table like '%{$search_param}%'";
```

I also tried run the query without dynamic variables just text and i got the same thing.

```
$query = "select id, cat_id, book_title, writer, publisher, issue_year, copies, abstract from library where book_title like '%lord%'";
```

Nothing seems to work.

I've tested my query on mysql workbench and it works like a charm!

In all of three queries i never get a log of the first error_log and the second one yells at me 0 every time!

Could someone light the way please?

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Lets do something simple, first `mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error();` so we can see if there is any error.

Comment: @swapnesh the $table variable is holding a sting like book_title!

Comment: @TomMcPadden On my php script i'm not getting any result!

Comment: @DevZer0 i just tried what you said and i do not get any error!!!

Comment: @GeorgeSfitis you are not using `echo` or `print` to display your result..so how you are assuming it to get in the browser then?

Comment: @GeorgeSfitis So it's blank? Could it be that nothing in the database matches the query?

Comment: @swapnesh i use a print to display my query:
it prints this:
select id, cat_id, book_title, writer, publisher, issue_year, copies, abstract from library where book_title like '%ΒΙΒΛΙΟΓΡΑΦΙΑ%'

Comment: @TomMcPadden Like i said yes in the script it seems blank but the same query in workbench return the right result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the only thing suspicious here is the [charset/collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html) you're using, which might result in a case sensitiveness issue. Try [forcing a non-sensitive collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) and see what happens.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

A utf8_bin (or any *_bin for that matter) makes comparison *case-sensitive*. If setting the connection collation to insensitive works, that would explain the difference between your script and MySQL Workbench.

Anyway, I would set the **column** collation to case-insensitive to avoid this kind of issues.

Comment: My table collation is utf8 - utf8_bin.
About the forcing thing can you give me an example i haven't done it till now!
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks that was my problem hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 0):

```
The query getting correct answer.. 

Try this:

$i=0; // before start while loop,you need to initialize i

while ( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
   error_log($data['id']);
   $shelves['position'][$i]['id'] = $data['id'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['cat_id'] = $data['cat_id'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['book_title'] = $data['book_title'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['writer'] = $data['writer'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['publisher'] = $data['publisher'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['issue_year'] = $data['issue_year'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['copies'] = $data['copies'];
   $shelves['position'][$i]['abstract'] = $data['abstract'];
   ++$i;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that i've got the line you mentioned i just forgot to put in on the question!

Comment: it's ok..  you try fetch array "while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))"

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help.

```
$query ="select id,
                cat_id, 
                book_title,
                writer, 
                publisher, 
                issue_year, 
                copies, 
                abstract 
                from library 
                where ".$table." like "%".$search_param."%";
```

But it is not tested yet.